# Get the closest number match from an array, must be lower

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of numbers like:

```
[10000 , 15000 , 20000 , 25000 , 30000]
```

I get a variable, which will vary and can be anywhere within the arrays range, e.g 23,500.

I need to find the closest number from the array but it must be lower than the given variable, too.

What would be the easiest way to do this? (can use jQuery)

EDIT:

Ive tried this:

```
salary = data[3]; // what im trying it on, this = 60001


    // the array is built from a select
$.each($('#home-salary-from').children(), function(){

    salaryArray.push($(this).attr('id'))

})

    //returns [0, 10000 , 15000 , 20000 ...] etc up to 100000.

salaryFrom = salaryArray.filter( function(i){ return i <= salary }).pop();

console.log(salaryFrom)
    //always returns 100000 ??
```

Comment: Your array is sorted? How about a modified dichotomic search?

Comment: `var max = 23500, closest = [10000 , 15000 , 20000 , 25000 , 30000].filter( function(i){ return i <= max }).pop()`

Comment: `get Homework(); if (noClue) postToStackOverflow();`

Comment: i'd push searched value in temp array then sort array and get the next item value following the searched value, if any

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

```
var max = 23500, 
    arr = [10000 , 15000 , 20000 , 25000 , 30000],
    closest;

// Solution 1 
    closest = arr.push( max ) && arr.sort()[ arr.indexOf( max ) - 1 ];

// Solution 2
    closest = arr.filter( function(i){ return i <= max }).pop();

// Solution 3
    closest = arr.sort(function(a,b){ return max >= b ? 1 : -1;  })[0];

// Solution 4
    closest = Math.max.apply(null,arr.filter(function(i){ return max - i >= 0 }));
```

Comment: wow awesome. First solution is missing something though:
`...arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b})...`

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Hpkq/)

```
var x = [10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000];

function find_closest(y) {
    var z = [];
    $.each(x, function (i, val) {
        if (y > val) {
            z.push(val);
        }
    });
    z.sort();
    return (z[z.length - 1]);
}

alert(find_closest(23500));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like :

```
Array.prototype.closest = function(value) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] > res && this[i] < value) res=this[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

to be used like:

```
var numb = [10000 , 15000 , 20000 , 25000 , 30000].closest(23500);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zNrny/1/)

Comment: Assuming sorted array: `for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) { if(this[i] > value) return this[i-1] || 0; }` http://jsfiddle.net/zNrny/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000];
var v = 23500;

var out = arr
  .map(function(el) { return el - v; })
  .filter(function(el) { if (el < 0) return el; });

var found = arr[out.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, out))] || 'No match';
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUTha/)

Answer (score 0):

We can get closest value with these simple code snnipets -

```js
    function getClosestValue(array,value)
    {
      var closestValue = null;
      for(i=0; i<=array.length;i++)
      {
         if(array[i] > value && 
            (closestValue == null || array[i] < closestValue))
        {
        closestValue = array[i];
        }
    
    }
    
    return closestValue;
    }
    
    var numb = [10000 ,24000 ,20000 ,23700, 25000];
    alert(getClosestValue(numb,23500));
```